# C code that finds path in matrix between start and destination point

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, path

In an NxN matrix, the start and destination points are taken from the user. Below is a code that checks if there are paths consisting of only 0 numbers between these two points. This code also changes the 0 values in the path it finds to the number at the destination point. But from the recursive function, the program assigns the starting point to all 0 numbers it sees. I'm putting the situation I'm trying to do as a picture. Can you help me find where my mistake is?
[image: what ı want to do]

But the output of the program is as follows:
[image: output of the program]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define N 5
void dfs(int adj[][N], int i, int j, bool visited[][N], int poison)
{
    if (i < 0 || i >= N || j < 0 || j >= N || adj[i][j] != 0 || visited[i][j])
    {
        return;
    }
    visited[i][j] = true;
    adj[i][j] = poison;

    dfs(adj, i - 1, j, visited, poison); // Move left
    dfs(adj, i + 1, j, visited, poison); // Move Right
    dfs(adj, i, j - 1, visited, poison); // Move top
    dfs(adj, i, j + 1, visited, poison); // Move bottom
}

bool hasPathDfs(int adj[][N], int sx, int sy, int dx, int dy)
{
    bool visited[N][N];
    int i,j;
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            visited[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    int poison = adj[sx][sy];

    // Mark the start and end positions as part of the '0' trail
    adj[sx][sy] = 0;
    adj[dx][dy] = 0;

    dfs(adj, sx, sy, visited, poison);

    return visited[dx][dy];
}



int main()
{
    // 2D matrix with 1's as blocked and 0's as path.
    int matrix[N][N] = {
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {2, 3, 0, 3, 1},
        {0, 4, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 2, 4},
        {5, 0, 0, 0, 5}};
  
    // Find path
    int sx = 0, sy = 0, dx = 1, dy = 4;
    printf("Find path from (%d,%d) to (%d,%d):\n", sx, sy, dx, dy);
    printf("DFS: %s\n", hasPathDfs(matrix, sx, sy, dx, dy) ? "true" : "false");


    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            printf(" %d ",matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like your code is only trying to find a single path, between a single pair of cells.  Is that what you want?  Or do you in fact want to find a compatible set of paths between every pair of same-colored cells?

Comment: Yes,the second one is what ı want to do. I want to find a compatible set of paths between every pair of same-colored cells. But I can't do what I want because I'm a little weak in this algorithm and recursive functions.

Comment: Yeah, that's a trickier problem.  You may have to find multiple paths between two cells, since some of them may block other paths.  So in general, you may need to backtrack.

Comment: Agree with @Tom that this is a hard problem, especially for a beginner. Here's an [interesting discussion](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47685/strategy-for-solving-flow-free-puzzles) of how humans might approach a solution.